# I want to display something using Autocomplete + placeholder

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to show a name "I Live In" in the text box, like using placeholder option. So when I click on that text box a certain list of names should get displayed and "I Live In" this text should remain constant untill I select any option from the list.

How I can do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an easy method, using datalists. I think this is exactly what you've described in your question. It has autocomplete and placeholder:

```
<input list="something" name="something" placeholder="I Live In" />
<datalist id="something">
    <option value="A cave" />
    <option value="A house" />
    <option value="A castle" />
</datalist>
```

JSFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/wL3gmgdt/

And a PHPFiddle link with form processing: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/nrc3-159g

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
<form method="get" name="Country">
    <select name="Country">
        <option value="">I Live In</option>
        <option value='England'>England</option>
        <option value='Wales'>Wales</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

View this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/knt6prd7/

Answer (score 0):

Try [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/), it can do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this.
are looking for below one or something else?

```
  <select id="select_task">
       <option value="QuestionBank_AddNewPanel_Select_Round"selected="selected">Select</option>
       <option value="Course1">Arul</option>
       <option value="Course2">Vicky</option>
       <option value="Course3">Dava</option>
  </select>
```

JS fiddle link :http://jsfiddle.net/2jrt07ut/

Comment: no not this one... i got that ans,,, we can achive using datalist